# Installing a VM with Ubuntu 16 on m1 macbook air

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, ubuntu-16.04, apple-m1, parallels

I have an M1 MacBook air and hence I need OS images supporting ARM. I need to use Ubuntu 14 or 16 on VM for an important task. I have tried using Parallel Desktop's free trial. It works fine for the Ubuntu 20 (ARM) image (.iso) but when I try to start running VM with ubnutu 16 ARM image (from [this page](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04.4/)), it is stuck at the following stage ([see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL4mb.jpg)), I think there is probably some problem with the OS image.
Can anybody help me with running Ubuntu 16 (ARM) on a VM on my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

You can try UTM and emulate the 16.04 x86_64, but it will be very slow.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).